# Meteor Blaze template helper wait for collection find to "SELECT DISTINCT"

Tags: javascript, meteor

This Meteor client code needs to group documents from a mongo collection by a field 'category' and return a sorted array of the unique values of the field 'category'. I am using Blaze template helper which returns an array populated by a `collection.find.foreach` since I could not find easy to follow examples on how to aggregate mongo collection of the client, How can I get the helper to wait till the collection operation is ready? Thanks

```js
  'jobs': function(){
    let categories = []

    Jobs.find({}).forEach((doc) => {
      if(!categories.includes(doc.category)) categories.push(doc.category)
    })
    return categories.sort()
  }
```

**Update: example added**

collection Jobs has data like:

```js
{'category':'Inspection','label':'Pink','discription':'R...}
{'category':'Inspection','label':'Blue','discription':'U...}
{'category':'Inspection','label':'AOR', 'discription':'A...}
{'category':'Inspection','label':'Prep','discription':'P...}
{'category':'Inspection','label':'Chec','discription':'I...}
{'category':'Inspection','label':'Diag','discription':'D...}
{'category':'Service','label':'basic','discription':'Cha...}
{'category':'Service','label':'regular','discription':'C...}
```

I need the unique values of the field category, which are (Inspection, Service).

**update 2**
On the mongo shell, the solution would be:
`db.jobs.distinct( "category" )` which produces ["Inspection","Service"]

Comment: It appears you're asking for `How can I get the helper to wait till the collection operation is ready?`. Can you explain why that is the/a problem you are trying to solve or how it is not behaving as you'd like?

Comment: `return categories.sort()` returns undefined.

Comment: No it doesn't. At least not unless you've added code elsewhere (not shown) that messes with the implementation of `Array.prototype.sort`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort `Return value: The sorted array.` There is no case where `undefined` would be returned.

Comment: Yes. you are correct. Problem fixed. thank you

Answer (score 0):

All of the given code does not require Mongo's aggregate function but can be solved with normal query functionality:

`if(!categories.includes(doc.category))` can be solved using the `$in` operator and `.sort()` can be solved using the `sort` transform operation:

```js
'jobs': function(){
  return Jobs.find({ category: { $in: categories } }, { sort: { category: 1 } })
},
```

The returned value is a `Mongo.Cursor` which will trigger reactivity on changes.

Readings:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/

https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#sortspecifiers

http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Template-helpers

Comment: This solution requires a filled up array `categories` which is empty thus will not work. I updated my post with an example, all I need is the unique values of the field "category" without knowing them in advance.